# How to get the authentication information in ModelViewSet?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-viewsets

I am using rest framework with `ModelViewSet`

```
class DrawingViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = m.Drawing.objects.all()
    serializer_class = s.DrawingSerializer
    filterset_fields = ['user']
    def list(self, request):
        queryset = m.Drawing.objects.all()
        serializer = s.DrawingSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

With this script, I can use filter such as  `/?user=1`

Howver this `user=1` is not necesary when authentication information is used in script.
(Because one user needs to fetch only data belonging to him/herself)

How can I get the authentication data in `list`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to return data based on user him/herself, there is no need to pass user id. If your user is authenticated, you can have his/her ID via `request` so:

```py
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated


class DrawingViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    ...
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    def list(self, request):
        queryset = m.Drawing.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        serializer = s.DrawingSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do like this as the above answer or you can override the get_queryset method as well.

```
 def get_queryset(self):
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            return whatever you want to return
        else:
            return None
```